# Word for the practical portion of my Ph.D?

Tags: terminology

Is there a (reasonably common) verb I can use meaning *to perform the practical work* of one’s PhD thesis that I can use to put in the following blank:

> I have ____ my Ph.D. in the laboratory of Professor M. Hatter.

I can’t use *completed* because I’m lacking my defence as of I-don’t-yet-know-when-exactly.

Comment: What's wrong with "performed the practical work of my PhD thesis"?

Comment: If the only thing missing is your defence, then you should actually be a step further than "having performed the practical work" - you should have submitted your PhD thesis already. If this is the case, then say this in your statement, to avoid misconceptions.

Comment: Well, you could say the honest truth, which would be: "_I have **not yet completed** my Ph.D. in the laboratory of Professor M. Hatter._" And once it's actually done, you can take pleasure in removing the words "not yet". Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say

> I am pursuing my PhD in...

or

> I have undertaken my PhD research in...

Both work in this context.

Answer (score 2):

This may depend on your program, but stating that you've completed your candidacy will be understood by most. There's also [the term ABD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_but_dissertation) but that usually refers to a dissertation rather than a defense.

Perhaps stating it as "I am preparing to defend my Ph.D. dissertation/work/etc..." may also work.